# SQL Server locking for an UPDATE with WHERE clause and sub-SELECT

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, isolation-level

It seems that this topic is asked often, and I think I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562711/transaction-isolation-levels-and-subqueries) to my original question, but now I'm curious about a difference between that (and a few other answers I found) and my SQL:

```
update Foos set Owner = 'me' OUTPUT INSERTED.id where Owner is null and id in
  (select top 1 id from Foos where Owner is null)
```

I now understand that my original hypothesis is correct regarding the sub-select and concurrency, where a concurrent thread may `select` the same id as another thread is about to `update` that id. However, does my `where` clause in the `update` piece help prevent this race condition (in `read committed` level)?

My theory is that, while two threads may get the same id from the sub-`select`, only one would be able to `update`, because the `update` is atomic and includes the condition. The other thread would fail, or update zero records. Is that true?

Comment: Oops it looks like maybe this should have been posted on dba? Never knew that existed...

Comment: In addition to your concurrency concerns you are doing a top 1 with no order by. You may not always get the same 1 unless you specify an order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE AS 
 (
  SELECT ID, [Owner] 
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) rn 
  FROM Foos
  WHERE [Owner] IS NULL
 ) 
update CTE 
  SET [Owner] = 'me' 
OUTPUT INSERTED.id 
WHERE rn = 1
```